# Play framework 404 error with assets on stage mode

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've got a problem running my Play framework app on stage mode.

If I run the app on dev mode, with `play run` for instance, everything is ok.
If I compile the app with `play compile clean stage`, and then use `start`, all my assets are unreachable (I get a 404 error).

I'm aware of the bug/feature about empty files, but that's actually not the case here.

My route is the same as the doc:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Can anybody help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually sounds like Play Framework is able to get files with `//` in the path in dev mode, but not in stage.

So this should works on dev mode:

```
assets//images/image.png
```

But not in stage mode.
To correct this, just replace `//` with `/`