# play framework: no assets in production mode

Tags: playframework-2.0, development-environment, assets, production-environment

I have a strange problem. I have an app written in Play! framework 2.0.4. It uses some public assets (css/images/javascript). Everything's fine when I run it in development mode:

```
blus@vmblus:~/svn/blus> play
[info] Loading project definition from /home/blus/svn/blus/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /home/blus/svn/blus/project
[info] Set current project to blus (in build file:/home/blus/svn/blus/)
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.0.4, http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[blus] $ run

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Assets load in browser without any problem. But when I want to run **the same** app (not copied, not moved, just the same) in production mode assets are gone:

```
[blus] $ start 9000

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Play server process ID is 6845
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
```

Firebug shows:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://vmblus:9000/assets/stylesheets/main.css"
```

Every needed asset is not found. How is this even possible? And what can I do to fix this?

This is part of my `conf/routes`:

```
GET /assets/*file controllers.ExternalAssets.at(path="public", file)
```

And this is how I call my assets in views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.ExternalAssets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520668/play-framework-404-error-with-assets-on-stage-mode), but my paths have no `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `controllers.ExternalAssets.at` instead of `controllers.Assets.at`

That's most likely the reason.

Comment: I must admit, it worked with `controllers.Assets.at`, but I had to switch because I wanted to allow user to download some files, as suggested byt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451246/how-to-serve-uploaded-files-in-play2-using-scala).

Proper solution would be to combine these two methods I guess, right? Could you explain why this is happening? Or at least provide any links?

Comment: I just checked and everything seems to work with `controllers.Assets.at`, even file download. Thanks!